# Alamofire not working in xcode 7

Tags: swift, swift2, xcode7, alamofire

I am not getting any sort of error when puthing the import statement at the top of the file. Alamofire, from what I can tell, is recognized by xcode. It is when I try and access code from Alamofire when I run into problems. When I begin to type Alamo, the only auto complete I code I can use is "Alamofireversionnumber" and nothing more.

For clarification I am using xcode 7 and swift 2.

Comment: Strange. Try cleaning the project (Cmd + K).

Comment: I see the same behavior. Just don't worry about it. If you type `Alamofire.` (with the period after it), then command line completion works fine from that point on. The command line completion of that module name that seems problematic, but after that, it's fine.

Comment: Thank you Rob! That was the solution. Very strange behavior, must be a glitch with the Xcode 7.