# can't use alamofire class and method in Xcode9 Swift4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, alamofire

I am a beginner but I usually don't have an issue implementing pods to Xcode project. I can use alamofire seamlessly in Xcode8, but recently i just upgrade to Xcode9 and Swift4, but I don't know why Xcode doesn't recognize Alamofire class and methods,

the podfile to install alamofire is like this

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '10.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'alamofireTestApp' do
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.5'
end
```

I have tried to ctrl+B but the problem is still there, I can `import Alamofire`, but I can't find the method and its class, it just shows `Alamofireversionnumber`, here is the screenshot

[image: ibb.co/mHdZRb]

what went wrong in here?

Comment: run `pod update` in terminal and restart the project

Comment: i have tried but still have that issue :(

Comment: what's  your target development version

Comment: It may be issue with XCode suggestions. just write down full code !! It should work

Comment: This is longstanding behavior of Xcode and code completion. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/33685768/1271826. As iOS Geek said, type `Alamofire.re`, for example, and then hit escape key for code completion at that point, and you'll see reasonable code completion at that point.

Answer (score 4):

Yes I noticed that only **Alamofireversionnumber** is shown in y project too when I installed it using pods

Simple solution is just

-> **write Alamofire ScreenShot**1

[image]

**-> Alamofire.**

[image]

-> **Alamofire.re** then suggestion will appear

[image]

Comment: * internal facepalm moment * Thanks!